# How ubuntu cloud image instance persist writing to the console after systemd started?

Tags: server, cloud, systemd, console

I am creating the cloud image for ubuntu I a try to figure out, how it writes all informations on the serial console when running in the cloud.

I used this image:
https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/xenial/current/xenial-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img

When I try to recreate that behaviour on my image it stops writing after journald is started

```
[   11.192345] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel...
[   11.362003] systemd[1]: Mounted RPC Pipe File System.
[   11.461612] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[   11.555519] systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[   11.649353] systemd[1]: Mounted Debug File System.
[   11.743620] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
^[[r^[[H^[[2J

Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS euca-10-254-38-28 ttyS0

euca-10-254-38-28 login: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS euca-10-254-38-28 ttyS0
```

I want something similar like here:

```
[    3.469429] systemd[1]: Started Nameserver information manager.
[^[[0;32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started Nameserver information manager.
[    3.475530] iscsi: registered transport (tcp)
[    3.492282] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[^[[0;32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started Journal Service.
[    3.511329] iscsi: registered transport (iser)
[^[[0;32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started LVM2 metadata daemon.
         Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
         Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
         Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
         Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
[^[[0;32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started Set console keymap.
[^[[0;32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started Load Kernel Modules.
[^[[0;32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started Load/Save Random Seed.
[^[[0;32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
```

I added "console=tty0 console=ttyS0" to grub. I thought this is changed in /etc/systemd/journald.conf, but everything is default there.

Answer (score 0):

I think once `systemd` starts, it sending output to the `journal` instead of the `tty`. In `/etc/systemd/system.conf`, try setting `DefaultStandardOutput=` to either `journal+console` or `tty`.  Reboot to test.

You can the docs for any systemd directive by starting at `man systemd.directives` and looking up the directive.